# How do I get only one checkbox check action to trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of checkboxes and a function to add an input when checked. The problem I'm getting is that multiple inputs are appearing instead of one per checkbox.

```js
$("#myletters").change(function(e) {
  $("input[name='letters']:checked").each(function() {
    var letterChecked = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(letterChecked);
    $("#" + letterChecked).after(
      "<label id='" +
        letterChecked +
        "-school-label'>Please enter your " +
        letterChecked +
        " school<input id='" +
        letterChecked +
        "-school' type='text'></input></label>"
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myletters">
  A<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="A" id="C" />
  B<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="B" id="B" />
  C<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="C" id="A" />
</div>
```

Also what function should I use to remove the input if unchecked?

Comment: Posted an answer below, hope that helps you to validate as well before adding it, as any other answer below does not do that. And you mentioned you do not want it multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. For every change, you run a function for each checkbox.
If i had previously checked a checkbox, then, it's checked and your function related to ALL the checked checkboxes.

I would advise to run the function only once and not use the `.each` function. So, for every change in the checkboxes, if the "current" changed checkbox has been checked - add the input.

Check this [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trmsg065/).

```
$('#myletters input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var letterChecked = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(letterChecked);
    $("#" + letterChecked).after(
      "<label id='" +
        letterChecked +
        "-school-label'>Please enter your " +
        letterChecked +
        " school<input id='" +
        letterChecked +
        "-school' type='text'></input></label>"
    );  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code simplifies:

It targets all checkboxes and checks if the checkbox is `checked` using `is(:checked)` or not. If so, add the input, if not remove it.

```js
$("#myletters > input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
  var letterChecked = $(this).attr("id");
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).after(
      "<label id='" +
      letterChecked +
      "-school-label'>Please enter your " +
      letterChecked +
      " school<input id='" +
      letterChecked +
      "-school' type='text'></input></label>"
    );
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).next("label").remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myletters">
  A<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="A" id="C" /> B
  <input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="B" id="B" /> C
  <input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="C" id="A" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla Javascript, here's my approach. Feel free to ask questions if anything is unclear.

```js
const myletters = document.getElementById('myletters');
const inputContainer = document.getElementById('inputs');

const inputs = [...myletters.querySelectorAll('input')].reduce((acc, val)=> {
  const input = document.createElement('input'); // create an input for each checkbox
  input.id = `${val.id}_school`;
  input.placeholder = `${val.id}_school`;
  return { ...acc, [val.id]: input }; // and store it in an object under the checkbox id as key
}, {});

myletters.addEventListener('change', ({target: cb}) => {
  if (cb.checked) {
    inputContainer.appendChild(inputs[cb.id]);
  } else {
    inputContainer.removeChild(inputs[cb.id]);
  }
})
```

```css
#inputs { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myletters">
  A<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="A" id="A" />
  B<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="B" id="B" />
  C<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="C" id="C" />
</div>
<div id="inputs"></div>
```

Comment: @Mouser Not in Firefox or Chrome. It is not supposed to work in any Internet Explorer version. I've stopped coding for those years ago; if you need to support it, let Babel do the job for you.

Comment: It does in Edge (can't handle the spread operator on the queryselector). Use `Array.from`

Comment: You are referring to the dead version of Edge. The current version of Edge is based on Chromium and has all the same advanced Javascript capabilities that Chrome has. You should switch to that asap.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may also not want it to create multiple times the same one's.

So this might be all that you want:

```js
$("input[name='letters']").on("change", function(e) {
  if($(this).is(":checked") && !($(this).next("label").length > 0) ) {
    var letterChecked = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).after(
        "<label id='" +
        letterChecked +
        "-school-label'>Please enter your " +
        letterChecked +
        " school<input id='" +
        letterChecked +
        "-school' type='text'></input></label>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myletters">
  A<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="A" id="C" />
  B<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="B" id="B" />
  C<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="C" id="A" />
</div>
```

Here we are also checking if it already exists. It is **validating** before it tries adding it again.

## Extension

If you want it to remove on dis-selecting it. (I know you have not asked for it :))

You may add an else condition and have it removed.

```js
$("input[name='letters']").on("change", function(e) {
  if($(this).is(":checked") && !($(this).next("label").length > 0) ) {
    var letterChecked = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).after(
        "<label id='" +
        letterChecked +
        "-school-label'>Please enter your " +
        letterChecked +
        " school<input id='" +
        letterChecked +
        "-school' type='text'></input></label>");
  } else {
    $(this).nextAll("label").remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myletters">
  A<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="A" id="C" />
  B<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="B" id="B" />
  C<input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="C" id="A" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This is a great suggestion, I'll include the additional check. Also what's the difference between using next and nextAll ?

Comment: `.nextAll()` method returns all next sibling elements of the selected element, while `.next()` method returns the immediate first sibling of the selected element.